# What is the probability drawing 4 cards so that at least one card doesn't belong to the set S = {2, 6, J, K}, given one card belongs to the set?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, card-games

> Four cards are drawn without replacement from a standard playing deck of 52 cards.

We can calculate $Pr($2 is in the draw $)=1-Pr($2 is not in the draw$)=1-\frac{_{48}C_4}{_{52}C_4}$, but I have no idea how to proceed further.

Comment: Well, what's the probability that all four drawn cards belong to $S$?

Comment: Note:  I can't really follow your calculation.  Why do you speak of the probability of "$2$ is in the draw"?  Why $2$ in particular?

Comment: I used 2 and I think same can be used for 6, J, K, but I am not sure how.

Comment: Well, I don't see the point of specifying values.  You method is sound.  the probability that at least one of the four is in the set is $1$ minus the probability that none or in the set.  Thus $1 - \binom {52-16}4/\binom {52}4$.

Comment: Now you need to compute the probability that all four are in the set and from there it is simple algebra.

Comment: @lulu So the negation of "at least one is not in the S" is "all are in set the S"? Then, is it $\frac{4^4}{52*48*44*40}$?

Comment: @lulu Since we want at least one card to belong to the set S but not all of them, is the answer $1-\frac{_{52-4*3}C_4}{_{52}C_4}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The total number of hands:
$$\binom{52}4$$
The number of hands with no cards belonging to the set $S=\{\text{twos, sixes, jacks, kings}\}$:
$$\binom{52-16}4=\binom{36}4$$
The number of hands with at least one card in $S$:
$$\binom{52}4-\binom{36}4$$
The number of hands with at least one card in $S$ and at least one card not in $S$:
$$\binom{52}4-\binom{36}4-\binom{16}4$$
The conditional probability of "at least one card not in $S$" given "at least one card in $S$":
$$\frac{\binom{52}4-\binom{36}4-\binom{16}4}{\binom{52}4-\binom{36}4}=\frac{210000}{211820}=\frac{1500}{1513}$$